# Axios Get Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, async.js

Coding in Node-JS on Windows 10.

```
arr = axios.get(siteUrl, { name: 'daniel' }, { timeout: 1000 }).then(function (response) {
  const html = cheerio.load(result.data);
  const dwnld1 = html("[class='do_download hi_res']");
  const dwnld2 = html("[class='do_download tar']");
  var dataT = html("[class='download_table']");
  return [dwnld1,dwnld2,dataT];
}).catch(function (error) {console.log(error);})

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

This may be a selector error, but after inserting a debugging `console.log` into my then function, it does not output to console.

Comment: axios get is asynchronous - `arr` wouldn't be `undefined` - it would be a `Promise` that stringifies as `{}` not `undefined`

Comment: get is async you need a await keyword

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier or use `.then`

Comment: yup even better

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier @Jaromanda X I already have a `.then` for the axios call, where would I put one to make this work?